# Vuex state returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, console, vuex

I'm having an issue where I am getting an unexpected value from the store.

I have a component with one method:

```
methods: {
    setProduct(product) {
        this.$store.commit('basket/empty');
    
        console.log(this.$store.state.basket.items);
  
        this.$store.commit("basket/addToBasket", {
            id: product.id
        });
    },
},
```

It simply empties the basket and adds a new product, thus one product can exist in the basket at any one time.

My issue is that the console log is returning a product.

[image]

Rather than an empty array. If I remove

```
this.$store.commit("basket/addToBasket", {
    id: product.id
});
```

it is returns

[image]

Please can someone tell me why the console.log is returning items, when the commit hasn't taken place yet?

***Basket.js***

```
const state = {
    items: []
};

const getters = {};
const actions = {};

const mutations = {
    empty (state) {
        state.items = [];
    },
    addToBasket (state, product) {
        state.items.push(product);
    },
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

Comment: Observer in console **observes** the changes and is refreshed when you add an item. So, everything looks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer console is able to update the data when logging a reference variable, like an Array or Object.

When you click to expand in the console, it shows you the variable as it is *at the time you click the console*, not at the time it was logged.  That means it does not necessarily reflect the value of the `items` variable at the time it was logged.

In this case, the `items` array is empty when the log happens, but by the time you click to expand the properties, the array contains the new id.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/sdjwcerz/) that illustrates this a little more.